# Optimistic @Version is increased when update fails due MongoSocketOpenException

Tags: spring-data-mongodb

I would like to have working retry when Mongo is temporary unavailable. I simply down Mongo and start process with `mongoTemplate.save()` in loop with sleep.
When I up Mongo, `save()` is rejected due OptimisticLockingFailureException, because although prevoius `save()` was rejected because Mongo was down, entity version was increased

I'm confused:

1. Is it a bug in Spring Data that version is increased even if database is down?
2. Should I give up because it is wrong idea to retry when connection to Mongo failed?
3. Should I manually decrease @Version when `save()` failed?

spring-data-mongodb 4.1.5